# Step-over Properties not functioning correctly in VS 2015

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2015

I have the selection to "Step over properties and operators (Managed Only)" checked and when I hit F11, it still debugs in to the functions parameters property.

So if I try:

```
function myfunc(propA, propB){}
```

When I debug (Hit F11), it will go into the getters/setters for "propA' and "propB" before hitting the code location for myfunc().  This setting is supposed to have the user step OVER properties, but this does not seem to be the case.  Anyone have a solution for this?

[image: VS 2015 Options - Debugger]

Comment: Which programming language do you use? I could not create a sample based on the form you provide. SR. So could you please share us a detail sample so that we could reproduce this issue? Thanks.

Comment: VB.net
`code
    Public Property PropA() As String
        Get
            Return _PropA
        End Get
        Set(value As Sttring)
            _PropA = value
        End Set
    End Property

Execute(PropA)

function Execute(ByVal SomeString As String) ...End function
`
So When you step into Execute(PropA) it steps in to the Property of PropA before stepping into the Execute function.  Its supposed to Step Over stepping in to P{ropA property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just debug it in my VS2015 Enterprise version with update 3 in windows 10 64 bit.

(1) Please reset your VS settings like this steps:

TOOLS->Import and Export Settings Wizard->Reset all settings->select “No, just reset settings, overwriting my current settings”->Choose a Default Collection of settings(I use the "General" settings), and make sure that your app is in debug mode not release mode and platform=Any CPU. I also get the pop window warning like the screen shot 2 in my side if I use the default VS settings in my side.

[image]

(2) Run your VS as the admin, view the result. Or you could run your VS in /Safemode, debug it again.

I just use the English VS version in English windows 10 Environment, but if the same app has this issue just in your side, maybe we would think about the Environment itself.

[image]

Comment: Already was using that option and was still stepping in to the parameter properties before stepping in to function.  Resetting VS did not do the trick either.  Sigh...

Comment: @Argyle Ghost, What is your VS2015 version? I use the VS2015 Enterprise version 14.0.25431.01 update 3. So please make sure that you use the latest update 3. I reset the VS settings using the Import and Export Settings Wizard and select the "General" settings. One important issue is that not add the breakpoint in your parameter properties line, just debug your app using F11(Step Into) directly, view the result. Do you use the same sample shared by Leo Liu? Or you could share us your sample, so we could really repro it in our side.

Comment: Private _userid as String

        Public Property UserID() As int32
            Get
                Return _userid
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As int32)
                _userid = value
            End Set
        End Property
  
CallToManager.Save(UserID)

// Calls

Class CallToManager
 public sub Save(ByVal UserID as string) // BREAK POINT IS SET HERE
  ...
 End Sub
End Class

Comment: The breakpoint is not set anywhere in the properties, it is set on the line of code that is calling function the function.  I have been using VS since the 2003 Version, so I am not new on how to set break points.

My Version is:  MSVS 2015 Professional Ver. 14.0.2543101 Update 3

Comment: `Private _userid as String

        Public Property UserID() As int32
            Get
                Return _userid
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As int32)
                _userid = value
            End Set
        End Property

// BREAK POINT IS SET HERE
CallToManager.Save(UserID)  


Class CallToManager
 public sub Save(ByVal UserID as string) 
  ...
 End Sub
End Class`
@Jack Zhai-MSFT

Comment: It is the most simple, straight forward code.  
1.  A line of code passes in an argument that is a property of that class
2.  Instead of entering the function that it is calling, it is always stepping in to the property (F11) first before stepping in to the called function.  

This is really bothersome, if you have many lines of code that call functions that use many properties, it takes a lot longer to debug.

Thank you so much for helping me out here :) @Jack Zhai-MSFT

Comment: @Argyle Ghost， Actually I just test it using the sample shared by Leo-MSFT, it works normally in my side. In addition, not add your code in the comment, could you share a screen shot in your previous issue directly like the sameple provided by Leo-MSFT? So we could use the same sample as yours, of course, as my previous reply, does it work if you use the sample provided by Leo-MSFT? If it works well, maybe we would think about your project, but if it still has this issue, we would think about the Environment or others.

Comment: unfortunately I cant show code due to company policy.  Your code as well steps in to the properties before stepping in to the function.  Looks like we are not going to be able to past this issue.  I will investigate if this is happening to many others at my company and if it is happening on a large scale, I might get someone to look in to it here.  Thank you for all your help!  I really appreciate it  :)

Comment: @Argyle Ghost, If it doesn't work in your side, I think we would think about the Environment, since it works well in my side and Leo's Environment. I just edit my answer, if possible, you could test it in your side.

Comment: Rerset my VS 2015 today and chose no (Again) about step-over property and this time for some reason (cause i have done that 3x already) it "took", LOL.  Thanks everybody.  Have a wonderful 4th of July weekend. @Jack Zhai-MSFT

Answer (score 0):

> This setting is supposed to have the user step OVER properties, but this does not seem to be the case. Anyone have a solution for this?

This Step-over Properties is works fine on my machine, below is my test sample, you can check it.

```
Module Module1

Sub Main()
    PropA = "Test"
    Execute(PropA)
End Sub

Private _PropA As String
Public Property PropA() As String
    Get
        Return _PropA
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        _PropA = value
    End Set
End Property

    Function Execute(ByVal SomeString As String) As String
    Return "Hello"
End Function

End Module
```

And if I uncheck that option, it will steps into the properties before stepping in to the function. Below is my test sample, you can refer to it for more detail info:

[image]

Comment: No, your misunderstanding.  You got it the opposite way, lol.  I DONT want to step in to the properties.  There are no breakpoints in the properties, I want to step OVER the properties and go straight to stepping in to the function.  That checkbox option should make it step OVER properties but it is not, it ALWAYS steps INTO the properties before stepping in to the function.  @Leo-MSFT

Comment: @ArgyleGhost, Aaaahhh sorry..., I have updated my answer, you can check it. But I could not reproduce your issue, please check my code and the sample, hope this can help you. If this issue is still persist， please let me know for free. I will keep follow.

Comment: Hmm....bummer.  cause there are a few people at my company where this is happening.  We have it checked and it still steps in to the properties prior to stepping in to the function  :(